# Issue with Spark job's in Yarn Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In my spark Yarn cluster, when I investigating the jobs using SparkUI, I am always getting 3 consecutive jobs with same id, runid and batch.

The first job of those were taking multiple more time then remaining jobs. Please explain why.

[image]

Comment: Please show your code and spark-submit command